# Query to sum each master item to stock

Tags: mysql

i want to sum the item sorted by master item and it should be sum different for each item, all i can do is like this, could you give me some help to fix my query?

this is the query

```
WITH Tb0 as
( SELECT masuk.no_masuk as no_bukti,masuk.tanggal,masuk_detail.kode_bahan,masuk_detail.qty as qty_masuk,0 'qty_keluar' from masuk,masuk_detail WHERE masuk.no_masuk=masuk_detail.no_masuk
    UNION
SELECT keluar.no_keluar as no_bukti,keluar.tanggal,keluar_detail.kode_bahan,0 'qty_masuk',keluar_detail.qty as qty_keluar from keluar,keluar_detail WHERE keluar.no_keluar=keluar_detail.no_keluar
)
, Tb1 as
(
SELECT tanggal,kode_bahan,qty_masuk,qty_keluar,Row_Number() over (order by tanggal asc) as OrderId
    FROM    
        Tb0
)

SELECT T1.kode_bahan,T1.tanggal,T1.qty_masuk,T1.qty_keluar,(Sum(T2.qty_masuk) - Sum(T2.qty_keluar)) as Balance FROM Tb1 as T1 
        INNER JOIN
            Tb1 as T2
            ON T1.OrderId >= T2.OrderId
            Group By T1.kode_bahan,T1.tanggal,T1.qty_masuk,T1.qty_keluar
            Order BY tanggal
```

and this is the result
[result query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MZCY.png)

all i want is sorted by kode_bahan(master item) and tangggal(date) like this

[result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdxMZ.png)

Comment: please share the scripts for the create and insert sample data. Image sharing will not work.

Comment: @AmitVerma sure this is the create and insert sample data https://pastebin.com/uprJM60Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, im using subselect and union all to solve this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33905621)